# Can Visual Studio's Find be hooked for new file types?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions, dsl-tools

I've created an entity modeling DSL (https://github.com/msawczyn/EFDesigner) and would like to give the users the ability to search the model while viewing it (for class names, attribute names, association endpoint names, etc.).

I'd like to hook into Visual Studio's `Find` feature and display the search results in the `Find Results` window, then put focus on the element when they select it in `Find Results`, in the same way that selecting a `Find Results` code entry navigates you to that line of code. I'm currently doing that kind of navigation with Errors and Warnings in the `Error List` window.

I can't seem to find documentation anywhere on the API for hooking into `Find` functionality. Based on Visual Studio's architecture, I'm assuming this is a service.

Is this an extension point? Is it not doable? If it can be done, would someone please point me to the documentation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you please share us much more information about the real type you want to add to the Find results window, as far as I know, it has the default formats/types even if we could custom it: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saraford/2008/11/24/did-you-know-you-can-customize-how-search-results-are-displayed-in-the-find-results-window-363/

Comment: The file is a Microsoft DSL model, so it's XML. The extension is custom (.efmodel). But even if the user searches in .efmodel files,. I'd like to hook it so that, when they click on the result, I'm informed and can bring the DSL designer to the foreground and make the DSL element in question active. I can do the latter, but just don't know how to hook into the find results window. Hopefully that clarified somewhat.